# How to change the default Xmonad configuration off all users?

Tags: xmonad, haskell, configuration-managment

The canonical way to configure Xmonad is by creating the file `~/.xmonad/xmonad.hs`

However, I would like to change the default Xmonad configuration for *all* users, and not just for myself.

I have tried placing a configuration file in `/etc/xmonad/xmonad.hs` but it didn't work.

How can I change the system-wide Xmonad configuration?

Answer (score 1):

For lack of a better way, one thing you could do is place a default configuration in the system-wide `/etc/skel` directory:

> The /etc/skel directory contains files and directories that are automatically copied over to a new user's home directory when such user is created by the useradd program.

[Source.](http://www.linfo.org/etc_skel.html)